# PHP - While editing form field using 'select' default value or previous value getting deleted

Tags: php, drop-down-menu

```
        <td>Three And Half Yearly</td>
<td><input type="date" class="form-control" name="Three_and_Half_Yearly" value="<?php echo $Three_and_Half_Yearly; ?>"></td>
<td><select class="form-control" name="Three_And_Half_Yearly_DO_NO"> <option value=""></option>
                                                                <option value="Upcoming">Upcoming</option>
                                                                <option value="Completed">Completed</option>
                                                                <option value="On_going">On going</option>
                                                                <option value="Postponed">Postponed</option>
                                                                <option value="Canceled">Canceled</option>
                                                                <option value="<?php echo $Three_And_Half_Yearly_DO_NO; ?>" selected disabled hidden><?php echo $Three_And_Half_Yearly_DO_NO; ?></option>
                                                                </select></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Four Yearly</td>
<td><input type="date" class="form-control" name="Four_Yearly" value="<?php echo $Four_Yearly; ?>"></td>
<td><select class="form-control" name="Four_Yearly_DO_NO"> <option value=""></option>
                                                                <option value="Upcoming">Upcoming</option>
                                                                <option value="Completed">Completed</option>
                                                                <option value="On_going">On going</option>
                                                                <option value="Postponed">Postponed</option>
                                                                <option value="Canceled">Canceled</option>
                                                                <option value="<?php echo $Four_Yearly_DO_NO; ?>" selected disabled hidden><?php echo $Four_Yearly_DO_NO; ?></option>
                                                                </select></td>
```

Above is part of my form field, whenever i run my PHP update query, the default or previous values getting replaced with null values. please help me to keep the old values and edit the other 'select drop-down' values.

My php update query is,

```
$query = mysql_query("UPDATE Inspection_schedule SET 
                                Client_Contract_Number = '$Client_Contract_Number',
                                Currently_Using = '$Currently_Using',
                                MBPS_EAM_Number_RIGT ='$MBPS_EAM_Number_RIGT',
                                Model_and_Type = '$Model_and_Type',
                                LFour_Yearly = '$LFour_Yearly',
                                LFour_Yearly_DO_NO = '$LFour_Yearly_DO_NO',
                                Six_Monthly = '$Six_Monthly',
                                Six_Monthly_DO_NO = '$Six_Monthly_DO_NO',
                                One_Yearly ='$One_Yearly',
                                One_Yearly_DO_NO = '$One_Yearly_DO_NO',
                                One_and_Half_Yearly = '$One_and_Half_Yearly',
                                One_And_Half_Yearly_DO_NO = '$One_And_Half_Yearly_DO_NO',
                                Two_Yearly ='$Two_Yearly',
                                Two_Yearly_DO_NO = '$Two_Yearly_DO_NO',
                                Two_and_Half_Yearly = '$Two_and_Half_Yearly',
                                Two_And_Half_Yearly_DO_NO = '$Two_And_Half_Yearly_DO_NO',
                                Three_Yearly = '$Three_Yearly',
                                Three_Yearly_DO_NO = '$Three_Yearly_DO_NO',
                                Three_and_Half_Yearly = '$Three_and_Half_Yearly',
                                Three_And_Half_Yearly_DO_NO= '$Three_And_Half_Yearly_DO_NO',
                                Four_Yearly='$Four_Yearly',
                                Four_Yearly_DO_NO = '$Four_Yearly_DO_NO',
                                Remarks = '$Remarks' WHERE ID=$Id");
```

Comment: Can you include your "PHP update query" as well, please?

Comment: I have tried this way also... but found no luck <option value="" selected disabled hidden><?php echo $Two_And_Half_Yearly_DO_NO; ?></option>

Comment: No, what I mean is can you put you "PHP update query" in the question so I can see it....

Comment: @man0v  my update query is added

Comment: Can you put any other relevant code, please? You must have code that is setting up the variables $Four_Yearly_DO_NO and $Three_And_Half_Yearly_DO_NO

Comment: @man0v  if(isset($_POST['submit1']) && $_POST['submit1'] != ""){
     $Three_And_Half_Yearly_DO_NO=$_POST[' Three_And_Half_Yearly_DO_NO'];
$Four_Yearly=$_POST['Four_Yearly'];
$Four_Yearly_DO_NO=$_POST['Four_Yearly_DO_NO'];

Comment: Please post this in the question, not here. It's hard to read. Anyways, out of what you've posted, you never retrieve any new data. You only update the data. You must have a query that is doing a "select" and populating your values in case there is no post.

Answer (score 0):

```
    I have made the droop down list dynamic and solved the issue...    
    <td><input type="date" class="form-control" name="LFour_Yearly" value="<?php echo $LFour_Yearly; ?>"></td>
    <td><select class="form-control" name="LFour_Yearly_DO_NO"> <option value=""></option>
    <?php
$statusquery=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM inspection_status");
$statusrowcount=mysql_num_rows($statusquery);

for($i=1;$i<=$statusrowcount;$i++)
    {
                                                                            $statusrow=mysql_fetch_array($statusquery);
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $statusrow["status"] ?>"
    <?php
    if ($row['LFour_Yearly_DO_NO']==$statusrow["status"])
    {   
    echo "selected";
    }
    ?>
    ><?php echo $statusrow["status"] ?><?php}?></select> </td>
    </tr>
```